# Reference request: Roger Howe's Schur lectures

Tags: reference-request

I have spent a lot of time trying to track down the following without any luck:

Perspectives on invariant theory: Schur duality, multiplicity-free actions and beyond,
The Schur lectures (1992) (Tel Aviv), 1995, pp. 1–182.MR1321638 (96e:13006)

by Roger Howe.

Does anyone know where I could find a copy?

Comment: Me too, please!!

Comment: The link on Google books (unfortunately, apparently without preview): http://books.google.com/books?id=EhEZAQAAIAAJ

Comment: My own copy is too fragile to be reproduced and Roger ran out of offprints a while ago, but he may have xerox copies. Some libraries also have it - have you tried ILL?

Comment: http://www.math.ethz.ch/~khorosh/teaching/sym_functions/list.html
Incomplete?


Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be a (complete?) scanned version:

[Chapters 1-4](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~khorosh/teaching/sym_functions/howe_ch1-4.pdf)

[Chapter 5](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~khorosh/teaching/sym_functions/howe_ch5.pdf)

[Appendix](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~khorosh/teaching/sym_functions/howe_app1-6.pdf)

[References](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~khorosh/teaching/sym_functions/howe_ref.pdf)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! And the whole website is great!

Comment: в "колхозе" много полезных книг он  доступен через торренты или знакомых

Comment: Sadly, the links are no longer active.  It is such a great article that, with Dr. Howe's permission, it would wonderful if it had a permanent online home.

Comment: @darij grinberg, do you have another link to this?

Comment: @TomCopeland: At this point, only libgen seems to have it: http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=howe+schur&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def

Comment: @darijgrinberg, great site. Thanks.