# SO(p,q) and Howe Duality

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I recently learned of a relationship between the representations of the groups $SO(p,q)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ which is part of an apparently much larger set of ideas known as Howe Duality.  My question is a bit open ended, but can someone point me to a good entry point (review articles, lectures) for learning more about Howe duality and in particular the $SO(p,q)$-$SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ duality?  Thanks.

Comment: It is related to Capelli identities see wiki and ref therein. Sorry need to run now.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85562/reference-request-roger-howes-schur-lectures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good introduction is "Non-Abelian Harmonic Analysis: Applications of SL(2,R)" 
by Roger Howe and Eng Chye Tan, especially Chapter III, Section 2.

Comment: Jeffrey -- thanks for the reference -- and for your previous answer to what is known about the unitary dual of $O(p,q)$.

Comment: To complete the reference Jeff makes, this readable softcover book is published in the Universitext series by Springer-Verlag, New York, 1992.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked in this?

MR0986027 (90h:22015a)  Howe, Roger . Remarks on classical invariant theory.
 Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.  313  (1989),  no. 2, 539--570.